# Bootstrap Dropdown is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've added the dropdown in the header.html which i included in the index.html of an angular app.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown profile hidden-xs">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="meta">

                        <span class="text">{{slUserObj.username}}</span>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" role="menu">

        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="showProfile();main.page='profile'">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </span>My Account</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="showProfile();main.page='profile'">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </span>Carreir Details</a>
        </li>
        <!--<li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            </span>Messages</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                            </span>Settings</a>
        </li>-->
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="logout()">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
                            </span>Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

here is the index.html

```
<section id="main-wrapper" class="theme-default">
<!-- Page wrapper -->
<header id="header" ng-include="'views/header.html'" ng-show="isAuthenticated"></header>
<!-- Left Sidebar Navigation -->
<aside class="sidebar sidebar-left" ng-include="'views/left-sidebar.html'" ng-show="isAuthenticated"></aside>
<!-- Content wraper -->
<section class="main-content-wrapper" ng-class="{'main-content-wrapper':isAuthenticated,'main-content-wrapper-full':!isAuthenticated}">
    <!-- Main content view  -->
    <div ui-view></div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></div>
</section>
<!-- /Content wraper-->
```

Now the dropdown in the header.html is not working once unhiding the header block after login, but its working when i'm refreshing the page after login.

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle or a Plunkr, it will be easier for us to assist you

Comment: can't really figure out what's going on... there's gotta something else blocking the dropdown. It's a little hard to debug without the code. Please try to make a plunkr like this one : http://plnkr.co/edit/WWXuddwaFi0vW3MMFDGB?p=preview